# How do I send a longblob as image/jpeg?

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql

I'm stuck trying to get an `express` server to answer an image file loaded from a `mysql` database. All of this is running on a robust AWS EC2 image running Rocky Linux (CentOS8).

I have a jpeg/jpg image stored in `mysql` as a `LONGBLOB`.

I describe how I upload and store the image below.

In the node-express implementation of a GET endpoint, I need to send (`res.send`) the binary data so that a browser renders it as an image.

Here is the URL that the browser requests:

```
https://my.domain.name:7003/personae/personaPicture?personaPictureID=fb5e2a5e-5996-4055-8e2a-b95707d76eea
```

In my IDE (VisualStudio code), I have the following:

```
const imageData = {
  data: (502547) [...<lots of bytes> ],
  type: 'Buffer'
}
const imageType: 'image/jpeg'
```

Here is endpoint code where I am trying to send the image:

```
res.type(imageType);
res.send(imageData);
```

The endpoint returns normally -- here is the console log:

```
GET /personae/personaPicture?personaPictureID=fb5e2a5e-5996-4055-8e2a-b95707d76eea 200 0.15 ms - 1784290
```

The result, in Firefox - `v110.0 (64-bit)` - is a broken image.

In the inspector of the "Developer Tools", when I mouse over the img, it says:

```
Could not load the image
```

I've spent the last few hours stepping through the code in `res.send`. It appears to me that `express` is turning the `imageData` (a `Buffer`) into `json`. That doesn't sound right.

I've been digging through documentation and a multitude of web sources with no joy.

I'm aware that this may be GIGO issue. The image is uploaded using the `file-upload` component. The middleware is saving the inbound image as a temporary file:

```
app.use(fileUpload({
  useTempFiles : true,
  tempFileDir: '/home/tms/tmp',
```

The POST endpoint that collects the upload looks like:

```
const image_upload = req.files.image_upload;
const temporaryFilePath = image_upload.tempFilePath;
const imageType = image_upload.mimetype;
const imageSize = image_upload.size;
const imageName = image_upload.name;
const imageEncoding = image_upload.encoding;
const imageMD5 = image_upload.md5;
```

The values look reasonable to me.

I store these fields in MySQL, and I use the following SQL to store the imageData:

```
(LOAD_FILE('<temporaryFilePath>'))
```

That field receiving that value is a `LONGBLOB`.

I note that value of `imageEncoding` is `7bit`. I don't see that "7bit" encoding anywhere as I step through `res.send` in the debugger. There are several places in the server code that have an `encoding` variable, and it's value is never defined.

I've tried fiddling with base64 encoding `imageData`, and that doesn't seem to help.

With any luck, this is something simple that I've overlooked in the documentation.

I hope this community can help my find the error of my ways.

I appreciate your collective attention.

Comment: From MYSQL Command Prompt, what is result of SELECT @@max_allowed_packet; ?

Comment: The response is 67108864 -- more than enough.

Comment: I have an update with more information, but the stackoverflow edit quure is full. I upload the file using `curl`, and I've used `wget` to save the results of simply accessing the original file as an img. I then used `wget` save the results of my endpoint call.

The size of the original is 503547. The size of the endpoint response (which should be the same) is 1784290 -- 3.5 times larger!

I'm now investigating `Buffer` sizes and content in the service as it steps through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found and solved the problem.

The problem was that the data I was attempting to send was a literal object rather than an instance of `Buffer`. Once I see the problem, it is obvious from the code fragment in my original question:

```
const imageData = {
  data: (502547) [...<lots of bytes> ],
  type: 'Buffer'
}
const imageType: 'image/jpeg'
```

Here is the code that works in the above example:

```
const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(imageData.data);
res.set('Content-Type', `${imageType}`);
res.send(imageBuffer);
```

I saw the "type: Buffer" in the broken code and didn't see the curly braces around the value!

I appreciate the attention. I'm leaving this question here, and answering it myself, in hopes that it may help other developers who need to do the same thing.